# Uncheck boxes when another is checked

Tags: python, tkinter

So the problem is with the `if` function, it just won’t work. It totally ignores all value changes and does not change any value at all. What is wrong with this code?

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

CheckVar4 = tk.IntVar()
CheckVar5 = tk.IntVar()

C4 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Medium terms", variable = CheckVar4, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 12)

C5 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Hard terms", variable = CheckVar5, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 8)

if CheckVar4.get() == 1:
    CheckVar5.set(0)

if CheckVar5.get() == 1:
    CheckVar4.set(0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `if`s only run once. You need to register an action to the checkboxes that fire (and unset the other one) when you click on them.

Comment: Do you want to use radio button ?

Comment: "one of many" choices should be done with radiobuttons, not checkbuttons. I realize that doesn't answer your question, but this behavior of being able to select only one is built-in to radiobuttons.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe want to use radio buttons instead? Example bellow from [here](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_radiobuttons.php):

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

v = tk.IntVar()

tk.Label(root, 
        text="""Choose a 
programming language:""",
        justify = tk.LEFT,
        padx = 20).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(root, 
              text="Python",
              padx = 20, 
              variable=v, 
              value=1).pack(anchor=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(root, 
              text="Perl",
              padx = 20, 
              variable=v, 
              value=2).pack(anchor=tk.W)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
C4 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Medium terms", variable = CheckVar4, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 12, command=lambda:CheckVar5.set(0))

C5 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Hard terms", variable = CheckVar5, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 8, command=lambda:CheckVar4.set(0))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Typo error line 16 and 18. Missing widgets `pack()`

```
if CheckVar4.get() == 1:
    CheckVar4.set()

if CheckVar5.get() == 1:
    CheckVar5.set(0)

C4.pack(padx=0)
C5.pack(padx=0)
```